# What is wrong with my 'Save File' php code?

Tags: php, web, elgg

The question is simple but i will give some background information to hopefully make answering it easier.

So, I am working with the ELGG framework and taking information from a form and the text boxes in it in hopes to print that data to a simple text file.

Unfortunately, for some reason this has been giving me lots of trouble and I cannot seem to figure out why no matter where I look.

Code is as followed

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
//Get the page
$title = get_input('title');
$body = get_input('body');
$date = date("l jS  F Y h:i A");

//remove any possible bad text characters


$FileName = $title . ' ' . $date;
//print to file
//get filename and location to save
$folderName =  '/Reports/' . $FileName . '.txt';
$ReportContent = "| " . $body . " |";

//write to the file
file_put_contents($folderName, $ReportContent, 0);

//error check to see if the file now exists
if (file_put_contents($folderName, $ReportContent)) {
    system_message("Report Created (" . basename($folderName) . ")");
    forward(REFERER);
} else {
    register_error("Report (" . basename($folderName) . ") was not saved!");
    forward(REFERER);
}
```

So what above SHOULD do is grab the text from the title and body box (which i can confirm it does from the title at least) and then save it under the /reports/ folder (full path for the plugin is Automated_script_view/reports/ if needed). Yet I will always get the register error, and I cannot seem to find why.

I believe it has to do with the declaration of the folder (/reports/), as if I take that part away, it passes and submits, although it doesn't seem to actually save anywhere.

Any and all advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: file_put_contents is getting an absolute link. So it will try to save to /Reports where it probably doesn't have permissions to do so (or maybe the folder doesn't even exists. Add a dot at the start to make it relative to the path executing the script

Comment: Also, you're calling file_put_contents twice. Once for writing and the next to test if it wrote. Both times though, it is writing which is a bit wasteful. You should use the return of the first call to test the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Function  **file_put_contents(file,data,mode,context)**  returns the number of character written into the file on success, or FALSE on failure. Note the following corrections and your script will work just fine:

1 Your File name has an 'illegal' character ":" coming from the $date part of the string you concatenate to form the filename.

2 Remove  `file_put_contents($folderName, $ReportContent, 0);`   Since the function returns an integer, simple use:

```
if( file_put_contents($folderName, $ReportContent) > 0 ){
//true
 }else{
//false
}
```

Comment: or its better to check with `!== false`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with since if( int x) will return true.

Comment: no its not wrong :) but from the logic think its better :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I took your advice and while it made my code 'cleaner' and better than it was before, unfortunately I still get an error whenever i try to put in the file location before the name. I am not sure but I have a feeling that because everything is coming from ELGG framework, it may not like trying to save anything to the folders/using its information. Do you know if I can use the /path/ to save somewhere like my documents to test?

Comment: I learned it was actually ELGG stopping this from working, so essentially, this comment fixed it perfectly as it could!